# Выводит мусор в текстовый файл C++

Tags: c++

есть проблема в том, что выводит мусор в текстовый файл, не знаю где несостыковка, но думаю прочитав код вы поймете в чем заключается задача программы.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    char Name[15];
    double school;
    double count;
    double square;

} Person;

Person* InitPerson()
{
    Person* Info = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("\nВведите: название, школу, количество, площадь >:");
    scanf("%s", Info->Name);
    scanf("%lf", &Info->school);
    scanf("%lf", &Info->count);
    scanf("%lf", &Info->square);

    return Info;
}

void DisplayPerson(Person* Info)
{
    printf("\n%s %5.1lf %5.1lf, %5.1lf year \n", Info->Name,
        Info->school, Info->count, Info->square);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    FILE *ourfile;
    Person* Info;
int BufSize = sizeof(Person);
    ourfile = fopen("MyFile.txt", "w+");
    Info=InitPerson();
    DisplayPerson(Info);
    fwrite(Info, BufSize, 1, ourfile);
}
```

Кстати, букву выводит нормально, а вот числа совсем нет.
   Вот скрин вывода в текстовый файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: double это 8 байт в формате IEEE 754, и вот эти вот 8 байт вывелись ровно как в памяти и хранятся, это не мусор, всё работает нормально.

Comment: У вас дикая помесь С и С++

Comment: @andreymal, так а вы не знаете как сделать, чтобы вывело мои числа, которые нужно?

Comment: @t1nzy этот код вывел ваши числа, всё в порядке.

Comment: Вместо `fwrite` нужно `fprintf`.